# "Unable to attach a .csv file" on Gmailing an attachment by a button in android stdio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to Gmail a .csv file by clicking on a button in android studio. But I am getting "Unable to attach file" every time.

```
private String file = "myfile.csv";
private String filecontents, text="Hey people";
Uri path = null;
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File filelocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), file);
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                //i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                String subject ="Details";
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,path);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,text);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share using.. "));
             }
        });
```

Expected result: .csv should be attached properly.